# singelton with c array?

Tags: objective-c

I am  trying to put into my singelton a c array, in order to later build a ring buffer.
It gives me error when trying to set the property .

```
    @interface globals : NSObject
    {

        SInt16 bufBuf[2000];
..
    }

@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) SInt16 bufBuf;
```

then `@synthesize` it on the .m file

i have to say that i am going to write an audio callback buffer into `bufbuf` very fast.(its ok?)
whats wrong and how can i fix that ?
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what the error is, but it could well be that the type you use in your property is not the same as you use in your member variable.

Try something more like this:

```
@interface globals : NSObject {
  SInt16* bufBuf;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) SInt16* bufBuf;
```

You'll need to `malloc` the buffer in your `init` method.

Comment: thanks but its not array. i couldnt understand how this pointer would help me .

Comment: `SInt16 a[]` is the same as `SInt16* a`. C doesn't really have arrays. It has pointers and some syntactic sugar to make it look as though it does.

Comment: wow! i fill stupid , thanks a lot. where can i read more about it ?

Comment: it now seems that it doesnt help because you cant write to global during audio callback it takes too much time and it crashes.

Comment: In your `init` method you need to do `bufBuff = malloc (sizeof(SInt16) * 2000);` and `free(bufBuff)` in `dealloc`. You can read more about pointers and arrays in any C (not Objective C) tutorial.

Comment: thanks a lot. in what init ? the one in the singletone class or the one in the audio callback class ? why allocating it will take less time ? i am really frustrated about it. just cant get it .